# Python : Referencing Data from JSON file in python

Tags: python

I'm currently making a username + password login system and have a file containing the usernames and passwords of previously signed up users. The side of the programme that signs up users works perfectly, but I have tried to implement a system to check the data from the file and sign the user in if they input the right data.

Edit: One combination from the database, it's all structured like this; [["ExampleUsername", "BadPasswrdo14130"]]

This is the code:

```
# Login Interface using files as a 'login database' of sorts?

import json

def autoSave():
    with open("Accounts.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(accounts, outfile)


def loadUsers():
    with open("Accounts.json") as infile:
        return json.load(infile)

def existingUser():
    eUsername = input("Your Username » ")
    ePassword = input("Your Password » ")

    for index, item in (accounts):
            if item[1] == eUsername and item[2] == ePassword:
                print("Logged in")
            else:
                print("Login failed")

def createUser():
    global accounts
    nUsername = input("Create Username »  ")
    nPassword =  input("Create Password »  ")
    entry = [nUsername, nPassword]
    accounts.append(entry)
    accounts = accounts[:500000]
    autoSave()

accounts = loadUsers()
```

How would I retrieve data from the database file and check that data with the data that the user inputted?
I've tried already but it does not work, always says login failed, which is this bit of the code:

```
def existingUser():
eUsername = input("Your Username » ")
ePassword = input("Your Password » ")

for index, item in (accounts):
        if item[1] == eUsername and item[2] == ePassword:
            print("Logged in")
        else:
            print("Login failed")
```

Comment: Please show a part of the generated JSON so one can see its structure

Comment: [["ExampleUsername", "BadPasswrdo14130"]] The username and password respectively in the JSON :)

Comment: From what I read in the code, "item[1]" and "item[2]" would refer to the second and third letters of the password.  I'm guessing you mean to pass accounts into "enumerate", and probably ought to compare item[0] to username and item[1] to password?

Answer (score 1):

In your code `accounts` is a list. When you're iterating over it, you get *sublists*. You should iterate over the sublists to get the username and password.

So you can do:

```
def existingUser():
    eUsername = input("Your Username » ")
    ePassword = input("Your Password » ")
    for item in accounts: #no need for braces
        if item[0] == eUsername and item[1] == ePassword:
            return "Logged in"
        else:
            return "Login failed"

print existingUser()
```

In your current code you seem to have forgotten that in Python list indexes start with `0`.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. One thing though, I discovered while testing your code that because I had two of the same usernames in the code with differant password combinations, it would return both login failed and login sucessful, how would I implement a system to prevent people using the same username, if it already existed?

Comment: @Csarg, no problem. Since you're doing it in a function, you can _return_ from it thus stopping the cycle. And then you just print the returned value. Please check out my edit

Comment: I guess thats a nice way of solving that issue, but how could I stop duplicate accounts all together? It's gonna annoy me! :P

Comment: @Csarg, you want users to stop creating duplicate accounts? Then you should check whether such a login/password combination already exists in `createUser()`.

Comment: Gathered this much, but how would I do this much? I tried doing it like that but didn't really work too good.

Comment: @Csarg, _WTF_? I don't understand what you're saying. Could you please clarify what you've done, what didn't work and how do you want it to work?

Answer (score 0):

@ForceBru

This is the code I tried to prevent dup accounts, it doesent allow you to dupe accounts but when making a new account, it says its already created when its not, but creates it anyway.

```
def createUser():
global accounts
nUsername = input("Create Username »  ")
nPassword =  input("Create Password »  ")
for item in accounts:
    if item[0] == nUsername:
        return "Account Username already exists, try again"
    else:
        entry = [nUsername, nPassword]
        accounts.append(entry)
        accounts = accounts[:500000]
        autoSave()
```